# Manual Crontab on Wordpress server not firing with Abandoned Cart Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a wordpress site setup and has been running for years.  We have installed the Woocommerce Abandoned Cart Lite plugin, but don't want to use the standard WP_Cron and would prefer to use a standard cron job so we don't have rely on visitors to the site.  Also it free ups some resource.

I have disabled the standard cron in the **wp-config.php** file with this line

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

And have set a crontab file by ssh-ing into the server on the command line, running `crontab -e` and then adding this line 
`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/wp-cron.php`

This is the correct path to the wp-cron.php file but it is not running.  I know because the abandoned cart plugin is supposed to send emails after a certain time to the user if they do not complete checkout.  I can see my abandoned cart there, and the seetings are all correct and the email template is set up, but no emails are going out.  (the test email works).

Have i done something obviously wrong?